# XSLT Concatenate Elements

Tags: xslt

I am not an XSLT expert and seek some help here.

Here is my XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Target_Root>
<RecordHeader>
    <FileHeader>1234567</FileHeader>
</RecordHeader>
<TransDetails>
    <TransHeader>
        <FileHeaderRec/>
        <BatchHeaderRec/>
        <OrderingPartyRec/>
        <TransBody>
            <TransactionRec/>
            <DescRec>
                <_0160>
                    <RecordCode>1</RecordCode>
                    <VariantCode>A</VariantCode>
                    <Description>Srii1 </Description>
                </_0160>
            </DescRec>
            <DescRec>
                <_0160>
                    <RecordCode>1</RecordCode>
                    <VariantCode>A</VariantCode>
                    <Description>Srii2</Description>
                </_0160>
            </DescRec>
            <NameBenRec/>
            <CityBenRec/>
        </TransBody>
                    <TransBody>
            <TransactionRec/>
            <DescRec>
                <_0160>
                    <RecordCode>1</RecordCode>
                    <VariantCode>A</VariantCode>
                    <Description>Srii3 </Description>
                </_0160>
            </DescRec>
            <DescRec>
                <_0160>
                    <RecordCode>1</RecordCode>
                    <VariantCode>A</VariantCode>
                    <Description>Srii4</Description>
                </_0160>
            </DescRec>
            <NameBenRec/>
            <CityBenRec/>
        </TransBody>
    </TransHeader>
    <BatchTrailerRec/>
    <FileTrailerRec/>
</TransDetails>
```

and my intended output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Target_Root>
<RecordHeader>
    <FileHeader>1234567</FileHeader>
</RecordHeader>
<TransDetails>
    <TransHeader>
        <FileHeaderRec/>
        <BatchHeaderRec/>
        <OrderingPartyRec/>
        <TransBody>
            <TransactionRec/>
            <DescRec>
                <_0160>
                    <RecordCode>1</RecordCode>
                    <VariantCode>A</VariantCode>
                    <Description>Srii1 Srii2</Description>
                </_0160>
            </DescRec>
            <NameBenRec/>
            <CityBenRec/>
        </TransBody>
        <TransBody>
            <TransactionRec/>
            <DescRec>
                <_0160>
                    <RecordCode>1</RecordCode>
                    <VariantCode>A</VariantCode>
                    <Description>Srii3 Srii4</Description>
                </_0160>
            </DescRec>
            <NameBenRec/>
            <CityBenRec/>
        </TransBody>
    </TransHeader>
    <BatchTrailerRec/>
    <FileTrailerRec/>
</TransDetails>
```

As seen, I am trying to concatenate values of elements under a segment that falls under one context id. While I could do it using my in-house application, it seem to be highly time consuming. Has anybody faced this requirement before? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can built upon an identity transform. See the comments for explanations.

Suggestion for **XSLT 1.0**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Do nothing for DescRec elements that have a preceding sibling DescRec -->
  <xsl:template match="DescRec[preceding-sibling::DescRec]"/>

  <!-- For Description elements, concatenate the content of all the Description elements
       within the same TransBody context -->
  <xsl:template match="Description">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::TransBody//Description">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For **XSLT 2.0**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Do nothing for DescRec elements that have a preceding sibling DescRec -->
  <xsl:template match="DescRec[preceding-sibling::DescRec]"/>

  <!-- For Description elements, concatenate the content of all the Description elements
       within the same TransBody context -->
  <xsl:template match="Description">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::TransBody//Description" separator="''"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Brilliant work,  Thank you very much, @Thomas W. This works like a charm. :-D

Comment: I am willing to learn XSLT. Could you please suggest me a best way to go about it? Thank you.

Comment: If so far you've only dealt with procedural and/or object oriented languages, you should invest some time to properly learn XSLT because it takes some time to get used to. The classic way: Get your hands on an XSLT introductory book. I don't remember which one I had for learning--if you have access to a library with IT books, have a look what looks good to you. I think it's essential that the book offers exercises.

Comment: Of course, there are also online tutorials like [the one by Zvon](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTutorial/Output/), but I personally find working through a book more motivating. It's also motivating to have some simple problems of your own that you'd like to solve in the process of learning XSLT.